# How to crop polygon with latitude and longitude coordinates from geoTiff image in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, latitude-longitude, gdal, geotiff

I have GeoTiff image which contains latitude and longitude for each pixel instead of x,y coordinates.

My task is to crop this image on provided polygon by user. Currently I am trying GDAL for same, but didn't found perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

to crop or clip particular part from raster image use gdal libraries with either geojson or shape file. You need gdal-bin to clip/crop raster image. Use `gdalwarp` with `-of` parameter to specify output format(default GTiff-geotiff), pass your geojson path, your raster image path, path where you want to store output. Complete command looks like 
`gdalwarp -of GTiff -crop_to_cutline -cutline #.geojson #.tif #.tif`